# Dell 5470 display material

Tags: display

I would like to know whether the screen is made from plastic or glass?

Also, I need to know whether it is protected with any additional surfaces?

I want to try Displex in order to polish the screeen and some small remove the scratches.

Comment: Did you do any research? If so, what have you discovered so far?

Comment: It seems to be plastic but still waiting for Dell official response or other opinions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the material is, but most likely it is some type of plastic. Glass would not likely scratch easily.

**But wait...**

Before you try any chemicals, try this. Use a rubber pencil eraser.

[image]

1. Power it off and lay it flat as possible
2. Clean it with mild solutions and wipe dry with soft cloth
3. Lightly rub the eraser along the length of the scratch
4. It may take a couple of tries for the scratch to go away
5. Repeat for each scratch

Note: only use a clean eraser. DO NOT use one that has pencil led on it or you may damage the display further.